# The meaning ot "alums"

Tags: meaning

> White and Netflix will no doubt bring attention to Cesnik’s murder and the sex abuse cases at Archbishop Keough, but their work hinges on the investigative labor of Gemma Hoskins and Abbie Schaub, two alums of Archbishop Keough who have each spent several years researching Cesnik’s case.

Source: https://www.vox.com/2017/5/20/15643380/the-keepers-netflix-sister-cathy-cesnik-murder-mystery-review

Can you please tell the exact meaning ot the word "alums" in the context of my sentence. The definition (some kind of a mineral) that I have found out does not make much sense to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure in this context it's a short-hand of Alumnus or Alumni.

> A graduate or former student, especially a male one, of a particular school, college, or university.
>
> A former member of a group, company, or organization.

In this case [Archbishop Keough is a Roman Catholic high school](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seton_Keough_High_School).

Comment: Some would insist upon *alumna* and *alumnae* for women, and that *alumnus* and *alumni* are gendered masculine. This matter is far from settled, but it is one reason why *alum* (note: pronounced with the opposite stress from the chemical compound) is a useful shorthand, and *alums* even more so.